# How to avoid wp_nav_menu() ID conflict?

Tags: menus

How do I avoid ID conflicts if I use the same menu TWICE on one page.

FIRST

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 
'theme_location'=>'menu', 'menu_class'=>'menu', 'menu_id'=>'menu' ) );
```

SECOND:

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 
'theme_location'=>'menu', 'menu_class'=>'menu2', 'menu_id'=>'menu2' ) );
```

ID conflicts are like "Duplicate ID menu-item-2456"... Any solutions?

Comment: You are not supposed to use the same theme_location, can you define a second one?

Comment: This cannot happen with different `'theme_location'`s. I’ll remove my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not to call the same `'theme_location'` more than once. **Theme location** is intended to represent an explicit *location* within the *template*.

Just register a separate `'theme_location'` for each separate location within the template that you want to display a nav menu.

Consider your chosen `'theme_location'` names to be *semantic* names, representing the *template location* of the menu. You could use `'primary'` and `'secondary'`, or `'header'` and `'footer'`, etc.:

```
<?php
function wpse55380_setup_theme() {

    // Register nav menu locations
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'header' => 'Header Menu',
        'footer' => 'Footer Menu'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse55380_setup_theme' );
```

...or:

```
<?php
function wpse55380_setup_theme() {

    // Register nav menu locations
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary'   => 'Primary Header Menu',
        'secondary' => 'Secondary Header Menu'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse55380_setup_theme' );
```

Then, it is up to the **end user** to assign custom menus to each Theme Location.

Comment: Thank you :) Yes, this answers my question but what if I want to use "Header menu" as normal menu and exactly the same menu in compact version (e.g. it hides "Header menu" and shows "Compact Header menu" on blog to save space)? It's inconvenient to ask theme users to setup the same menu twice. Any suggestions?

Comment: For one: what is the *actual* difference between *Header Menu* and *Compact Header Menu*? Knowing the differences will help determine the best way to implement. For another: **I actually disagree that it is poor form to ask the user to define two separate menus for two separate use cases**. In fact, creating a responsive/mobile Theme may very well involve having the user define a full menu *and* a compact/abridged menu, to output depending on context.

Comment: "Header Menu" is EXACTLY the same as "Compact Header Menu". First hides and second appears to make more space for content. Yes, it's responsive/mobile behavior to save space. I don't want to affect CSS style to achieve that. In this particular case it should be rather the same because it only appears when POPUP window with content appears.

Comment: "*"Header Menu" is EXACTLY the same as "Compact Header Menu".*" It' **can't** be; otherwise, why even have two separate menus? If they're not different with respect to CSS, then **how** are they different?

Comment: Normal menu has height 150px and icons, second menu has height 30px, no icons, only text. First slides up off the screen and second slides down (to be visible) using jQuery.

Comment: Those sound exactly like CSS-related differences. All you need to do is pass a different value to the `'menu_id'` or `'menu_class'` parameter that you pass to `wp_nav_menu()`.

Comment: It's not that simple because I need to display TWO of them at the same time :) First is visible below overlay background and second above it. That's why I need two. Furthermore, second has position: fixed and follow screen and first has position: relative. Screenshot: http://gyazo.com/b575a2780f063a9abe0adcc11877805f.png?1339790184

Comment: Why display both at the same time? There are so many ways to skin this cat - ways that don't require outputting two separate menus in one semantic template location.

Comment: Back to this question because it's still not answered actually: even Twenty Thirteen developers wanted to have "Compact Header" and they duplicated original navigation at first and it has been removed in WP3.6-beta3. They didn't resolve duplicate IDs issue so they removed compact navigation altogether... Yes, there are situations when developers need to output two menus and it's becoming more and more common. See example as you scroll down: http://www.geckoboard.com/statusboard-features/ (you sometimes simply can't style normal navigation properly and that's a fact).

Comment: Nonetheless, I'll use separate locations (although mentally users think of it as of the same navigation) or I'll duplicate it with jQuery. Those are acceptable solutions!